# Upload more than 2GB file in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I am trying to upload a 2+ GB video file using FTP . When I click “Upload” button in browser control, the page is not getting post but the status in browser is DONE. The same works fine with video files less than 2GB.

I just added one page, with browser control and one button for posting the page.

Just clicked the button, to post the page with 2gb file.

The page was not posting to server.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little more? Some code examples maybe of the mark-up you're using...

Comment: I think you'll need to post a bit more info.  What control are you using?

Answer (score 1):

split the file up into smaller chunks, FTP those, and then re-combine.

Comment: My first problem , my page was not posted to the server with one browser control of file size of 2.1gb and button to post the page.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)

edit :  You can do files up to 2GB +  with ASP.NET using a third party solution that overrides the built-in request checking. This will work in all versions of IIS except IIS 7 integrated mode, which has a hard 2GB limit.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699488/file-upload-of-more-than-4gb/699512#699512)

Read this : http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/upload

Comment: How to combine smaller pieces of files in to one.

Comment: i am given one link in stack overflow . Try with that .

Answer (score 0):

There are limits imposed by browsers on the amount of data you can upload in a single request.
In IE I think it is 2gb.
What are you using?